# How to calculate sum of two columns from two different tables without where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following sql statement to sum values from two columns from two different tables. The statement can output but not the desired result.

```
SELECT
SUM(`_income`.rate) AS Income,
SUM(`_expense`.rate) AS Expense,
SUM(_income.rate)-SUM(_expense.rate) AS Balance
FROM `_expense`, `_income`
```

My table is here:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `_expense` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `qnty` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `CreatedByPHPRunner` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `remarks` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `_expense`

```
INSERT INTO `_expense` (`id`, `item`, `qnty`, `rate`, `date`, `CreatedByPHPRunner`,   `remarks`) VALUES
(2, 'Maian', 2, 20, '2013-08-15', 0, 'A tui kher mai'),
(3, 'Battery', 1, 2100, '2013-08-15', 0, 'A lian chi');
```

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `_income`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `_income` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `items` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qnty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `remarks` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedByPHPRunner` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `_income`

```
INSERT INTO `_income` (`id`, `items`, `qnty`, `rate`, `date`, `remarks`, `CreatedByPHPRunner`) VALUES
(1, 'TV chhe siam', 1, 1500, '2013-08-15', 'Ka hniam hrep', NULL),
(2, 'First Star', 1, 25, '2013-08-15', 'A loose-in aw', NULL),
(3, 'Mobile Chhe siam', 2, 200, '2013-08-13', 'Nokia chhuak ho a nia', NULL),
(4, 'Internet hman man', 1, 1500, '2013-08-14', 'Ka net min hman sak a', NULL);
```

Comment: I think you should sum over a union of the tables with a 0 value fot the missing column in either table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select income, expense, income-expense balance
from (select sum(rate) income
      from _income) i
JOIN (select sum(rate) expense
      from _expense) e
```

Comment: very nice. Better this than rather doing it in the application