# Query to get column totals and Subtract MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, select, transactions, subquery

I have a transaction table

I am able to get all the debit and credit transaction totals by property separately using these queries

```
SELECT property, SUM(amount) as creditamount FROM transactions WHERE transactions.type="CREDIT" GROUP BY property    

SELECT property, SUM(amount) as debitamount FROM transactions WHERE transactions.type="DEBIT" GROUP BY property
```

I am facing difficulty in having these two queries done in a single query so that i can subtract credit amount and debit amount for each row and list it according to the property

I tried using sub queries but multiple rows are returned.

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional aggregation may be what you are looking for.

```
SELECT property, 
 SUM(case when type = 'Credit' then amount else 0 end) as creditamount,
 SUM(case when type = 'Debit' then amount else 0 end) as debitamount,
 SUM(case when type = 'Credit' then amount else 0 end) -
 SUM(case when type = 'Debit' then amount else 0 end) as  diff
 FROM transactions 
 GROUP BY property
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use self join**

```
select debitamount , creditamount
from (select sum(amount) income
     from  transactions 
     WHERE transactions.type="CREDIT"  
     GROUP BY property) i
JOIN (select sum(rate) debitamount 
     from transactions 
     WHERE transactions.type="DEBIT" 
     GROUP BY property) e
```

Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246818/how-to-calculate-sum-of-two-columns-from-two-different-tables-without-where-clau?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)